# Sublime text 3 and PYTHONPATH environment variable (windows)

Tags: python, sublime-text-3

It seems that sublime text 3 on my machine isn't respecting the PYTHONPATH environment variable, meaning I cannot easily import modules in to sublime text. 
I've written a script to get around this but this feels clumsy and besides, I haven't had this problem on other machines.

Also, I have to add this line:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

in order to get python modules to import other modules on the same path. Is this a 'feature' or perhaps some problem with my python installation?

Comment: '    import os, sys'
    sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))      
    paths = os.getenv('PYTHONPATH').split(':' if os.name=='posix' else ';')
    for path in paths: 
        if not path in sys.path:
            sys.path.append(path)
'

Comment: That was supposed to be the code I used as a workaround for this problem. Can't get mini markdown to work as expected unfortunately.

Comment: use `\`` instead of `'`